# How to remove first selected tab from sheets selected for printing

Tags: excel, vba

I have the code, which identifies filled tabs with corresponding responsible person and then prints them as one file:

```
Sub printS()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With sht
            If Not IsError(Application.Match("Person1", .Range("C:C"), 0)) And .Index > 3 And Not IsEmpty(.Cells(13, 1)) Then
                sht.Tab.ColorIndex = 7
                sht.Select (False)
            End If
        End With
    Next
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut
End Sub
```

The problem is that Excel includes the tab, where the macro button is located into the selection. As result I get blank page in the beginning of each PDF. Is there any way to remove tab with macro buttons from tab selection by correcting existing code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be an If statement control inside the loop.

```
Sub printS()
Dim sht As Worksheet 
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With sht
    If .name <> sheets("THAT SHEET NAME HERE").name then 'this control will exclude your button sheet       
        If Not IsError(Application.Match("Person1", .Range("C:C"), 0)) And .Index > 3 And Not IsEmpty(.Cells(13, 1)) Then
            sht.Tab.ColorIndex = 7
            sht.Select (False)
        End If
    End if 'close block if 
End With
Next
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut
End Sub
```